# Passing argument to windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to be able to pass an argument to my windows application so that I can run the code based on the argument passed:

**Below is the function that is called when the windows application start running:I need this method to have arguments.**

```
Private Sub Start_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try
        Dim Mgr As New StartMgr
        Mgr.Import()  // from here controls goes to a class library and it the whole //code, I need this function Import(arg) so that it can run partial code based on args

        Me.Visible = False
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        Application.Exit()
    End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `StartMgr` defined, specifically the `Import` method?

Comment: My concern is how do I pass an argument to my start_load method? once I get the parameter in that method I can pass it on to Import() method.

Comment: What kind of “arguments” are you talking about? Windows command-line arguments? C# method arguments? .NET `System.EventArgs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean command line argument, I don't think there's much you can do unless you add a property to your class. But you can always access the args through this function [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to pass arguments to windows form application

Comment: @Pinu Yes, if you mean command line argument, just call Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() to get the arguments when ever you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use this:

```
Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(".", args)
```

Comment: please use English